# Why doesn't my Android activity refresh/redraw?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, refresh, redraw

RoomInfoActivity.java: http://pastebin.com/L9fFsFeH
(note: this is the 3rd activity launched by the same application, not that it should matter..)

AndroidManifest.xml: http://pastebin.com/QbvQaTf3

room_info.xml: http://pastebin.com/DFNABSNF

Image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16952797/temp_stuff/elfapp_ss04.PNG
(note: when I click on the button, "nothing" happens.)

Description: So what happens is the code compiles just fine, and the .apk is launched and run without any issues, but the RoomInfoActivity doesn't reflect the changes that are supposed to be made (such as changing the text of the TextViews and Button) when I click on the button. **I'm looking for the least complicated way to do these.**

**EDIT:** I have now made a change, I added this line `buttonCleaned.setClickable(true);`
under this:

```
rumInfo.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("entry"));
buttonCleaned.setText("Färdig med städningen");
rumStatus.setText("Status: "+checkStatus());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `onClick()` method ever called? I think you need to set the Activity as a click listener on the button, using the [`setOnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) method.

Comment: Ok, it works now, I used `buttonCleaned.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` and linked it to my `public void onClick(View v)` method.

Comment: Glad to read your application is working. You don't need to create a ``new OnClickListener() {}`` though, try just ``buttonCleaned.setOnClickListener(this)``. You activity already implements the interface :)